# Cant register a class

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a problem with putting a Class File into a Hashmap.

I am trying to create a Class which will register Commands (to work with them later)

```
public class CommandRegister {

    static HashMap<String, ICommand> commands = new HashMap<String, ICommand>();

    public static void addCommand(ICommand c){
        commands.put(c.getName(), c);
    }
}
```

This is the Interface (ICommand) I created

```
public interface ICommand {
    public String getName();
    public void run(Event ev);
}
```

And a Command Class

```
public class Help implements ICommand{

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "help";
    }

    @Override
    public void run(Event ev) {
        return;
    }
}
```

If I now run this Code in my main class it wont work.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        registerCommand();
    }

    private static void registerCommand() {
        CommandRegister.addCommand(Help);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make an instance of Help with the "new" operator:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        registerCommand();
    }

    private static void registerCommand() {
        CommandRegister.addCommand(new Help());
    }
}
```